# Add-AzureADGroupMember fails if user already exist.

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azuread/v2/add-azureadgroupmember

Add-AzureADGroupMember fails if user already exist. how to suppress error? I have tried to pass -ErrorAction parameters with "Ignore" or "SilentlyContinue" but it does not help!

command is like

```
Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $NewAzureADGroup.ObjectId -RefObjectId $userInformation.ObjectId
```

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap that argument in a "Try" "Catch" block:

```
Try {
Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $NewAzureADGroup.ObjectId -RefObjectId $userInformation.ObjectId
}
Catch
{
Write-Host "User Already Present in Group"
}
```

Otherwise you can submit a bug report [on GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-docs-powershell-azuread/issues).